# Trying to display the content of the component in a single card which hold <router-outlet> in it , but every initial load shows same component inside

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-router, router-outlet

so this is an app that shows the image of sun signs as and when you click on a specific sun sign from the cards in the grid. Now the one big card on the top shows the contents of each individual sun sign components which happens to be a single image of the sun sign. Now when I load the SunSignHome component initially the  shows the same component i.e.,SunSignHome component and I understand thats because the path given in Routes, but I want to know if theres any way I can keep this top card a defualt value when initially loaded or the only solution to this is to create another component?

please find the project here : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-rpfk3b)

tried creating another component.

Comment: You are much more likely to receive responses with attempts to help when you include the relevant code **in the question body**.  It is much less likely that people will bother with your question if they have to dig through links to 3rd party websites to even see what your code structure is.